# Will reusing the hero attribute and faction names from another game cause the new game to become a derivative work?

Tags: united-states, derivative-work

In DotA 1, the heroes are organized into three attributes: Strength, Agility and Intelligence and 2 factions: Sentinel and Scourge. Will reusing all of these names mentioned will cause a new game to became a derivative work, even through these names are apparently generic? (Some games have distinctive attribute/faction names, but this doesn't appear to be the case in DotA)

Comment: Will it? Speculation. Also, LEgal Advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Strength, Agility, Intelligence, Stamina:

Unlikely, given the vast array of *prior art* and the "Obvious to any practitioner in the field".

Virtually every RPG out there uses four familiar stats:

- Constitution/Stamina/Toughness
- Strength
- Dexterity
- Intelligence

This is such a deeply held trope, and so axiomatic to RPGs on or off computers, that I doubt any intellectual property is in play.  If it *ever* was, it has been completely undefended for the last 40 years, so it's much too late to now attempt to claim rights.

### Sentinel and Scourge

Let me dodge that one and generalize: Can you use   *Alliance-Horde?*
*Terran-Protoss-Zerg?*
*Empire-Rebellion?*
*Gryffindor-Hufflepuff-Ravenclaw-Slytherin?*

See, there's a real spectrum there!  The four names *alone* are so unique that J.K. Rowling would come after you if you used them *anywhere*.  But Empire-Rebellion is too generic to assert an IP claim over.

And if you pluck *non-paired* names from an IP, like Ravenclaw-Granger, that's not a problem either.  A Wild West movie with feuding families the Grangers and Ravenclaws, would be absolutely fine; whereas Ravenclaws and Gryffindors would not be fine!

DOTA 1, however, is a copyright morass. Many games permit fan-created "mods", ranging from the TM:PE traffic modeling mod in *Cities: Skylines* to the TSM auction pricing mod in *World of Warcraft*.  The mod is nothing without the game. The game author doesn't own the mod, The mod author doesn't own the game.  They coexist mostly by consent.

DOTA I was an arena "mod" to *Warcraft III* and there has been quite considerable fighting over ownership of that IP. Valve now owns it [but agreed to allow non-commercial use of the IP](https://web.archive.org/web/20120724090129/http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2012/05/11/valve-blizzard-reach-dota-trademark-agreement.aspx).

Even so, the Sentinel-Scourge pairing is only really important in DOTA I.  The pairing doesn't mean much in Warcraft III, as they are disjoint, like my Granger-Ravenclaw example above.

You would probably be fine, but the risk of trouble is exactly why **original games create original IP** - for instance Sentinels-Scourge *was not* reused in DOTA II!

Comment: In the case of Dota 1, that game used too much names from Warcraft, most of them have been changed to prevent the game from becaming a derivative work. "Sentinel" and "Scourge" are the factions of the Night Elves and Undead in Warcraft 3, respectively. But Valve could certainly keep just the faction names.